# Open in a new tab except if site is already open

Tags: javascript, tabs

Is there JavaScript that allows for opening sites in a new tab unless the site is already open in a tab and just use the already opened tab for the link?

Comment: What do mean by `open site in a new tab`? `window.open(strUrl, winName [, winParams])
` ?

Comment: What does this `just use the already opened tab for the link?` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers do not allow you to get information about other tabs for security reasons so no.